# Efficient way to find out which command was called?

Tags: parsing, go

I have a bot written in Go that is constantly parsing messages and has commands that users of the bot can call, all commands are prefixed with **bot#**

Let's say I have several commands and some of them are: bot#thing, bot#another, bot#fu, bot#special

To find out which command was called, I first check if the message is prefixed with "bot#", if it is, I split the message string by " " (as some commands can have an argument after) and then apply a switch to find out what command is it and call its appropriate function

```
if strings.HasPrefix(message, "bot#") {
args := strings.Split(message, " ")
switch args[0] {
case "bot#thing":
//do something...
case "bot#another":
//do something...
case "bot#fu":
//do something...
case "bot#special":
//do something...
//and more cases...
}
}
```

My problem is, as more commands are added I think this can get quite inefficient, specially since I check for the prefix on every message. Is there a more efficient approach to parsing the messages to find out which ones are a command and which command is it?

Answer (score 2):

Use a map:

```
var commands:=map[string]func([]string) {
  "bot#command1": doCommand1,
  "bot#command2": doCommand2,
 }

func processMsg(msg string) {
   if cmd, ok:=commands[msg]; ok {
       args:= // parse arguments
       cmd(args)
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you should use a string slice, as some bot commands may take multiple arguments.